# How would you interpret the relativistic action, and how does the mass alter the action exactly?

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, mass, action

How would you apply the lagrangian in special relativity? How do you interpret the expression?

The action is given by:
$$S=-mc^2 \int  d\tau$$

where $m$ is the rest mass. If I understand correctly the relativistic stationary principle maximizes the proper time of a particle. In other words a particle takes the path between two points in spacetime that maximises the spacetime interval.

However what does the mass term change about that exactly? Does a particle rather 'prefer' being massive or rather not? For example if we look at a pion that decays into 2 photons. It seems the preference is to transform the rest mass into energy. Is this true?

How do you interpret the relativistic action and how does the mass $m$ change it?
I am looking for a proper interpretation.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44947/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The same worldline between two events in spacetime makes that action stationary *regardless* of the value of $m$. Multiplicative constants in $S$ don’t affect the Euler-Lagrange equations.

Comment: [Normalization of the action in Special Relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/529682/)